# Bootstrap Date/Picker Not Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble implementing the boostrap/js/jquery date picker into my webpage. I am not sure if there is code I am missing or hwaat.

These are the includes in the head

```
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

This is the Mark Up

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
      <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></h1>
        <h3>Choose Your Dates</h3>
         <input type="text" id="datepicker"  value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015"/>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".datepicker").daterangepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

UPDATE
Looks like content loading problem

[image: console errors]

Comment: `$(".datepicker")` should be `$("#datepicker")`

Comment: made the change but it didn't help... I think that typo came from me swapping back and forth between class and id to see if one would work... there must be a problem beyond it tho... Thanks anyways!

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3dz1gs48/

Comment: Yah I see that, I will figure it out...  just thought it might be faster to ask the pros

Comment: On your src and href attributes, do https:// instead of just //

Comment: You'd need to post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're actually having.

Comment: @Daryl Those are protocol-relative URLs. Is there a problem with them?

Comment: @j08691, I just tried creating an empty html file with the protocol-relative URLs and I got the same error OP shows in his screenshot. I added the https or http protocol to the beginning of it and it retrieved the files just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("#datepicker").daterangepicker();
```

Comment: Instead of answering typo question, vote to close them as off-topic. There's a close reason made specifically for this. It tends to make answerers look like they're trying to farm rep from a question that can be solved with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're selector in your javascript is wrong. In your html, you've defined datepicker as an id. In your javascript you're referencing it as a class.

Comment: Instead of answering typo question, vote to close them as off-topic. There's a close reason made specifically for this. It tends to make answerers look like they're trying to farm rep from a question that can be solved with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing your datepicker input via a classname `.datepicker` that it doesn't have. Either reference it via it's id, with `#datepicker` or add `class="datepicker"` to the input element.

Comment: Instead of answering typo question, vote to close them as off-topic. There's a close reason made specifically for this. It tends to make answerers look like they're trying to farm rep from a question that can be solved with a comment.